# Properly inserting a nodes into a Linked List C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

Good Evening! I am trying to create a C++ Linked List that will create a random number & store randoms in 100 nodes. I haven't gotten any errors in the code I created but when I run the program, the output loops the number "42" to the point where I have to terminate the program. Please help. The code is below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

struct Node{
    int xdata;
    Node* next;
};
struct Node *head;
void insert_node(int y)
{

    Node* temp = new Node;
    temp-> xdata = y;
    temp-> next = NULL;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=temp;
    }
    else{
        temp->next=head;
        head=temp;
    }
};
int main(){
int z =rand()%100 + 1;
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    insert_node(z);
}
while(head!=NULL)
{
    cout<<head->xdata<<" "<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check the loop where you print again, it iterates while `head` is not `NULL`, and when will `head` ever become `NULL`? Use another variable initialized to point to what `head` is pointing to, and reassign it in the loop to point to the next node in the list.

Comment: The answer to Life, The Universe, and Everything !

Comment: I see exactly what I was missing, thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

You need to advance your head pointer.

```
while(head!=NULL)
{
    cout<<head->xdata<<" "<<endl;
    head = head->next;
}
```

Comment: I don't recommend doing this way. Because after the loop, your head pointer is compromised you can't find your linked-list back after the printing.